# Issue setting custom headers in Ionic GET request

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, get

I am trying to make a GET request to my backend to retrieve data to display it.
However the GET request is failing and no data is retrieved, initially no error message is shown, but after a while my browser's console returns an error with "0" status code.

```
GET http://localhost:3001/api/promotions 0 ()
```

My code is as follows, what am I doing wrong?

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjViNDdkZGUwYWM4NDkzMWM4MGYyMGJkNSIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTUzNzEyMDQ1OCwiaWF0IjoxNTMxOTM2NDU4fQ.Lsm0BtGxfbtCWo-kHgQvxf3HyKudkwKuDh-TbVV78c4");
let opt = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/promotions', opt)
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  console.log("aaa");    
this.promotions = data.data.children;

console.log(this.promotions);
},
err => {
    console.log("No se pudo encontrar las promociones");
});
```

I am sure the token itself is correct since I have succesfully tried it out in Postman.

Comment: Do you use Angular 5 or 6? Because in those versions is the new HttpClient and there Headers is obsolet. There HttpHeader is the way to go and that one is immutable

Comment: It's angular 5, I know http is deprecated but it should work, for example I can post just fine to the backend.

Comment: What are the Request headers shown in network tab in dev console? Are they appropriate to what you set?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { RequestOptions ,Headers,Http} from '@angular/http';
```

This code is working for me.

```
   getDataPostAuth(url,body) {


      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
       options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ sessionStorage.getItem("token") );

      this.http.post( MainURL+url,body,options)
      .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
      });
      });
      }
```

This code is for post. You can change it according to your own requirement.